# Migrating from JSF 1.1 to JSF 1.2

Tags: jsf, migration, jsf-1.2

Can anybody tell me what things I need to keep in mind before migrating an application from JSF 1.1 to JSF 1.2?

Comment: Are you using Rational Application Developer or WASdev?

Comment: no I am going to use eclipse but we are migrating from websphere 6.1 to 8.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not much, really. JSF 1.2 is 100% backwards compatible with JSF 1.1. Only thing which you need to take into account that JSF 1.2 fixes many, really many bugs. So if you ever incorrectly assumed some specific JSF 1.1 application behavior as "normal" behavior, but which is under the covers actually caused by a bug, then it would seemingly break.

In any case, just run unit tests before and after the upgrade and fix the issues individually.

It's only migrating from JSF 1.x to 2.x which requires more work, for sure if you also need to change the view technology from JSP to Facelets. For that, refer this answer: [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0/4532870#4532870).

Comment: can you tell me is there any other way to run junit tests if we have not used annotations and also not extended TestCase class

Comment: Would I only need to replace the libraries and the system will be up and running?