# Moving from JSF 1.1 to JSF 1.2?

Tags: jsf

We have a old web application which is using JSF 1.1.

We now need to upgrade the JSF version from 1.1 to JSF 1.2.  How much effort is required for this?

What are the changes needs to be done in the application?

Comment: why 1.1 to 1.2 ? why not 2.x ?

Comment: it totally depends on what you have in your application. how many pages do you have, how big / complex are the pages, what external frameworks do you use, what component library do you use...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Migrating from JSF 1.1 to JSF 1.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833560)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Migrating from JSF 1.1 to JSF 1.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833560/migrating-from-jsf-1-1-to-jsf-1-2)